# Get list of line items from XML

Tags: c#, xml, msmq, econnect

I have an eConnect outgoing document pulled from MSMQ, i need to loop through the line items.
I've tried:

```
 XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/Sales_History_Transaction/eConnect/SO_Hist_Trans/Line");
```

(and several other attempts) with no success...

Here is the XML, how can i get a collection of Line items from the "Line" nodes so that i can then get the line item details?

```
 <Sales_History_Transaction:root>
   <eConnect ACTION="1" Requester_DOCTYPE="Sales_History_Transaction" DBNAME="TWO"        TABLENAME="SOP30200" DATE1="2013-05-03T09:24:09.970" SOPNUMBE="999999" SOPTYPE="3">
      <SO_Hist_Trans>
            <SOPNUMBE>999999</SOPNUMBE>
            <SOPTYPE>3</SOPTYPE>
           <Line>
                <CMPNTSEQ>0</CMPNTSEQ>
                <LNITMSEQ>998777</LNITMSEQ>
                <ITEMNMBR>0099999</ITEMNMBR>
                <ITEMDESC>Laptop</ITEMDESC>
           </Line>
           <Line>
                <CMPNTSEQ>0</CMPNTSEQ>
                <LNITMSEQ>777</LNITMSEQ>
                <ITEMNMBR>0099</ITEMNMBR>
                <ITEMDESC>Desktop</ITEMDESC>
           </Line>
           <Line>
                <CMPNTSEQ>0</CMPNTSEQ>
                <LNITMSEQ>679777</LNITMSEQ>
                <ITEMNMBR>0569</ITEMNMBR>
                <ITEMDESC>Memory</ITEMDESC>
           </Line>
      </SO_Hist_Trans>
    </eConnect>
   </Sales_History_Transaction:root>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your xml is not well-formed.

The root tag seems to consist of an undeclared namespace `Sales_History_Transaction` and the element name `root`. Have you missed the line in which `Sales_History_Transaction` is defined?

Once you have valid xml, it should be as simple (depending on namespaces) as:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(yourXml);
var nodes = xdoc.Descendants("Line");
```

Comment: i very well could have missed a closing line. I apologize for the formatting, the xml file is extremely large (too large to post and reformat). I'll try what you suggested.

Comment: @devHead it is clear that you have problems with XMl Namespaces. If you show a valid xml, you can get a working answer.

Comment: Thanks @I4V, i ended up figuring it out... there is a second part to this that i need done and i will upload the file to dropbox.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do the trick for your example? Or is this the same you tried that failed?

```
XmlDocument doc1 = new XmlDocument();
doc1.Load("yoururl"); //I don't know from where you load

XmlElement root = doc1.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/Sales_History_Transaction/eConnect/SO_Hist_Trans/Line");
foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) {
    Console.Out.WriteLine(node["CMPNTSEQ"].InnerText);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(node["LNITMSEQ"].InnerText);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(node["ITEMNMBR"].InnerText);
    Console.Out.WriteLine(node["ITEMDESC"].InnerText);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("------------------------");
}
```

Comment: Although it did help with the inner loop when obtaining the child elements.

Comment: I see that i mixed between VB and C# here. Of course should node("CMPNTSEQ").InnerText be node["CMPNTSEQ"].InnerText

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
XmlNodeList nodes = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("Line");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
  string txt = node["ElementName"].InnerText;
}
```

this enumerates through all the "Line" elements in the XML.